# How to build a link between a character table and a numeric table?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
c1 <- c("product a1","product a2","product a3","product b1","product b2","product b3")
c2 <- matrix (c1,nrow=2,ncol=3,dimnames = list(c("productline a","productline b"),c("1","2","3")))
company1 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0)
company2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)
company3 <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0)
data1 <- data.frame(company1,company2,company3,row.names = c1)
c2            
                   1            2            3           
productline a "product a1" "product a2" "product b3"
productline b "product b1" "product b2" "product b3"   

data1
            company1 company2 company3
product a1        0        0        1
product a2        1        0        1
product a3        0        0        0
product b1        0        1        0
product b2        0        1        0
product b3        0        0        0
result
            productline a   productline b
 company1        1               0         
 company2        0               2
 company3        2               0
```

I have a table data1 up here. Now I want to analyse data1. And the basic information is product a1，a2，a3 all belong to "productline a", product b1,b2,b3 belong to "productline b", like table c2 shows.

I want to combine table c2 and data1 to get the result table like I show up there.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why, in the `result` dataframe, does `company2` have 2 for `productline b`? It seems `company2` has products `product b1` (in `productline b`) and `product b2` (in `productline a`). Could you clarify?

Comment: In the way you described your data, I suppose you wanted to use `byrow = TRUE` when contructing matrix `c2`.

Comment: @C.Braun sorry, it is just my typing mistake. b1 and b2 all belong to productline b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach with base R:

```
i <- which(apply(c2, 1, function(x) rownames(data1) == x), arr.ind = TRUE)

rn <- rownames(c2)[i[,2]]

aggregate(. ~ rn, data1, sum)
```

which gives:

> ```
>              rn company1 company2 company3
> 1 productline a        1        0        2
> 2 productline b        0        2        0
> ```

---

Used data:

```
c1 <- c("product a1","product a2","product a3","product b1","product b2","product b3")
c2 <- matrix(c1, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
             dimnames = list(c("productline a","productline b"),
                             c("1","2","3")))

data1 <- data.frame(company1 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
                    company2 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0),
                    company3 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
                    row.names = c1)
```

Comment: I just try but there is an error: Error in i[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: @YouZhou It is working fine for me on the example data. Could you also [look at my comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778438/how-to-build-a-link-between-a-character-table-and-a-numeric-table#comment86572826_49778438)?

Comment: it works, thank you. But I have 1 more question. When I delete "byrow=TRUE" it makes an error. Could you tell me the function of "byrow"?

Comment: `byrow` builds the matrix rowwise; if you don't specify that, the matrix will be build columnwise